# can't retrieve map data from firebase firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this data model:
[image: data model]

and here is my code in flutter:

**services**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:ilab/services/User.dart';

class Services {
  final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tests');

  // test list from snapshot
  List<Test> _testsListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
   return snapshot.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return Test(
                details: data['details'] ?? '',
                name: data['name'] ?? '',
                price: data['price'] ?? '',
                type: data['type'] ?? '',
                package: data['package'] ?? '',
               indication: data['indication'] ?? '',
               method: data['method'] ?? '',
              general: data['general'] ?? '',
              specimen_type: data['specimen_type'] ?? '',
              time: data['time'] ?? '',
              notes: data['notes'] ?? '',
              preanalytic_precautions: data['preanalytic_precautions'] ?? '',
              ref_rangeUnits: data['ref_rangeUnits'] ?? '',
              add: data['add'] ?? '',
              dateFrom: data['dateFrom'] ?? '',
              dateTo: data['dateTo'] ?? '',
            );
    }).toList();

  
  }

// Get tests stream
  Stream<List<Test>> get Tests {
    return _db.snapshots().map(_testsListFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Test{
  final String details;
  final String name;
  final String price;
  final String type;
  // final String descText ;
  final String general ;
  final String preanalytic_precautions ;
  final String indication ;
  final String specimen_type ;
  final String time ;
  final String ref_rangeUnits ;
  final String notes ;
  final String method ;
  final String add;
  final String dateFrom;
  final String dateTo;
  final Map package;

  Test({
    this.details,
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.type,
    this.package,
    this.general,
    this.time,
    this.indication,
    this.method,
    this.notes,
    this.preanalytic_precautions,
    this.ref_rangeUnits,
    this.specimen_type,
    this.add,
    this.dateFrom,
    this.dateTo
  });

  factory Test.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
    return Test(
      details: doc['details'],
      name: doc['name'],
      price: doc['price'],
      type: doc['type'],
      method: doc['method'],
      indication: doc['indication'],
      preanalytic_precautions: doc['preanalytic_precautions'],
      specimen_type: doc['specimen_type'],
      general: doc['general'],
      ref_rangeUnits: doc['ref_rangeUnits'],
      time: doc['time'],
      notes: doc['notes'],
      add: doc['add'],
      dateTo: doc['dateTo'],
      dateFrom: doc['dateFrom'],
      package: doc['package'],
    );
  }
}
```

**Code**

```
         ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.h),
                    controller: scrollController,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      if (filteredTests != null) {
                      return Card(
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),  
                            child: _card(index)),
                      );
                      } else {
                        return Center(child: Text('لا توجد بيانات ',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Cairo')));
                      }
                    },
                    // itemBuilder: (c, i) => Card(child: Center(child: Text(items[i])))
                    itemCount: filteredTests.length,
                    itemExtent: 240.0,
                  )


// return different cardshape for different group of data
  Widget _card(int index) {
    try {
      Color selectedColour(index) {
        Color c;
        if (index % 4 == 0) c = Colors.cyan;
        if (index % 4 == 1) c = Colors.blueGrey;
        if (index % 4 == 2) c = Colors.blue;
        if (index % 4 == 3) c = Color(0xFFea9999);
        return c;
      }
      if (filteredTests[index].type == 'باقة') {
        return PackageCardDesign(
          packageName: filteredTests[index].name,
          package:  '', 
          price: '${filteredTests[index].price} YR',
          details: filteredTests[index].details.toLowerCase(),
          colour: selectedColour(index),
          icon: Icons.ac_unit_outlined,
          type: filteredTests[index].type,
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

the problem is that I can't retrieve package data from firestore, I tried to use some methods for ex:

```
    // for (var entry in filteredTests[index].package.entries) {
    //   print(entry.key);
    //   print(entry.value);
    // }

    // List St = filteredTests[index].package.map((k,v) => MapEntry(k,v)).values.toList();
    // print (St);

    // Map<dynamic, dynamic> vari = filteredTests[index].package;
    // vari.entries.map((entry) {
    //   String idx = entry.key.toString();
    //   String val = entry.value.toString();
    //
    //   print(idx);
    //   print(val);
    // })

    // Map<dynamic, dynamic> vari = filteredTests[index].package;
    // final fruitListAgain = vari.values.toList();
    // print(fruitListAgain);

    // print(filteredTests[index].package.runtimeType);
    // Map<String, dynamic> data = filteredTests[index].package;
    // // var value1 = data['some_key'];
    // for (var entry in data['package'].entries) {
    //   print(entry.key);
    //   print(entry.value);
    // }
Map<String, dynamic> data = filteredTests[index].package;
        for (var entry in data['package'].entries) {
          print(entry.key);
          print(entry.value);
    }
```

but every time I get this as answer:

NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.

I/flutter ( 3668): Receiver: null

I/flutter ( 3668): Tried calling:

Comment: Please dont use screenshots, try pasting the actual code

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)